# How do I get only some of the belongs_to model of a has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :replies
end

class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

I need to get the comments that only have replies from certain users.

I have this in my Comment model:

```
scope :with_replies_by_users, ->(*user_ids) {
joins(:replies).where(replies: { user_id: user_ids })
}


@comments = Comment.with_replies_by_users([1,2])
```

I think this will return all of the comments that have replies by 1 or 2.  But it returns *all* of the replies for those comments.  I need only those replies from 1 or 2.

Comment: I believe the splat operator *the asterisk* is creating a multi-demensional array. Try removing it from your  `with_replies_by_users` scope

Comment: @GregAnswer - I tried it both ways and I'm getting the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you still get all replies from all users with your scope example is because those conditions are used for querying **comments**. In other words, it only serves to determine which comments are fetched from the database.

For example, here is the SQL that is run with the scope:

```
>> comments = Comment.joins(:replies).where(replies: { user_id: [2, 3] })
Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" INNER JOIN "replies" ON "replies"."comment_id" = "comments"."id" WHERE "replies"."user_id" IN (2, 3)
```

This is just saying "select **comments** based on the result of an inner join with the replies table." The result of the replies is pretty much pointless right now because as soon as you access the replies attribute on any one of the comments:

```
>> comments.first.replies
Reply Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "replies".* FROM "replies" WHERE "replies"."comment_id" = ?  [["comment_id", 1]]
```

ActiveRecord will do a separate lookup in the replies table because it doesn't consider the scope from the comments lookup.

**A Solution**

To me it looks like you're more concerned about the replies than the comments. Therefore one way I'd approach this query is by querying the replies table instead, but with eager loading:

```
>> replies = Reply.includes(:comment).where(user_id: [2, 3])
Reply Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "replies".* FROM "replies" WHERE "replies"."user_id" IN (2, 3)
Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = 1
```

Finally, you have replies only for the specific user ids. You already have the comments this way too because of eager loading. For example, doing the following will not incur any extra fetches since these comments are in memory.

```
>> replies.map(&:comment)
```

But be careful not to access the replies attribute on one of the comment models *again*, or else ActiveRecord will do another fetch:

```
>> replies.map(&:comment).first.replies
Reply Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "replies".* FROM "replies" WHERE "replies"."comment_id" = ?  [["comment_id", 1]]
```

If you want to still make this a scope, it would now go in the Reply model:

```
scope :from_users, -> (*user_ids) do
  includes(:comment).where(user_id: user_ids)
end
```

Then call:

```
>> Reply.from_users [2, 3]
Reply Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "replies".* FROM "replies" WHERE "replies"."user_id" IN (2, 3)
Comment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = 1
```